# How to show params array in desired format in angular-ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angular-ui-router

I am using angular-ui-router.I want to pass one optional array parameter.I set params array as [1,2,...] then it is shown as

> **localhost:3000?params=1&params=2....**.

But I want to show as

> **localhost:3000?params=1,2....**

**Code**

```
.state('home', {
            url: "/home?params",
              templateUrl: "app/views/common/home.html",
              controller: 'accountCtrl',
          })
```

Please suggest me how do solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here before passing array directly to params we have to make it as string instead of array.

```
  var list =[123,4];
  for(var j in list) {
     if(paramslList) paramslList+=","+list[j];
     else paramslList= list[j];
  }
  $location.path('/home').search({params: paramslList});
```